# Reserve characters in a string

Tags: javascript

My string must have 2 characters and the characters there are not filled must be left as blank spaces

```js
let string = "  ";
string.unknownMethod("a");
```

What do I need to put into the `unknownMethod` function to get this output:
`" a"`

I tried using the concat method but it concatenates to the end of the string

Comment: I'm failing to understand what your question is

Comment: That's what "concatenate" means.

Comment: Okay, so you would be wanting to check length of string, if 1 add a space before. If in case string =s double space call invalid, and that should be all you need if it needs to be alpha only, do a fast regex check.

Comment: I expressed myself badly. I reformulated the question for clear understanding